# VSCode Code Actions not working with Rust

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I'm using VSCode with rust-analyzer. I can get the Code Actions menu to show up, but clicking on the items does nothing. How can I fix this?
[image: the code actions menu showing up correctly]

Everything else works fine. It's only the Code Actions that aren't doing anything.

I've already tried updating/reinstalling VSCode, rust-analyzer, and Rust.

Comment: Could be [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/issues/13759)

Comment: Also, while questions about issues with software development tools are on-topic, many suggest posting to the relevant issue-tracker instead, especially when its clearly a bug (sources: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365108) [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318619)). You are more likely to get faster, more direct resolutions and/or better troubleshooting guidance than you'd get here.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I posted here because I expected it to be a problem with how I'd set up my repository, rather than a problem with VSCode as a whole.

Comment: It could be, and whether or not it is a bug or caused by a bad configuration, I do encourage you to come back and self-answer when you find a resolution. Like I said, these questions are still on-topic and could be helpful to others in the future.